# why label is not being configured in function?

Tags: python, tkinter

my score label or chances count is not configured when i run the function. can anyone help on this? the question label changes perfectly but the score label does not change and i am unable to understand why is that so.

```
   def checkans(self):

        chances = 0
        score = 0
        count = 0

        while chances == 3:
            break
        else:
            operations=['+', '-', '*']
            a = random.randint(1,15)
            b = random.randint(1,15)
            random.shuffle(operations)
            op = operations[0]
            self.label.configure(text=(a,op,b))
            if op == '+':
                ans = a + b
            if op == '-':
                ans = a - b
            if op == '*':
                ans = a * b

            self.e.focus_set()

            if self.e.get() == ans:
                score += 1
                self.scorelabel.configure(text=('score', score))
            else:
                 chances += 1
```

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Is this tkinter, or some other GUI framework?

Comment: looks like you're comparing a string to an int, try: `int(self.e.get()) == ans`

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
def checkans(self):

    chances = 0
    score = 0
    count = 0

    while chances < 3:
        operations=['+', '-', '*']
        a = random.randint(1,15)
        b = random.randint(1,15)
        random.shuffle(operations)
        op = operations[0]
        self.label.configure(text=(a,op,b))
        if op == '+':
            ans = a + b
        if op == '-':
            ans = a - b
        if op == '*':
            ans = a * b

        self.e.focus_set()

        if self.e.get() == ans:
            score += 1
            self.scorelabel.configure(text=('score', score))
        else:
            chances += 1
```

**When you use `while` with `else` the else only executes once.**

Comment: The while loop here is pointless, because the user will have no chance to enter any new data before each iteration (ie: `self.e.get()` will always return the same value).